# Could not find sub module as defined in application.xml .glassfishStaleFiles Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: deployment, glassfish-3, war, ear, redeploy

After updating to Glassfish v.3.1.2.2 I continually get this error:

Application builds with no errors, on deploy using Maven Glassfish plugin:

```
mvn glassfish:redeploy
```

response:

Could not find sub module [appName.war] as defined in application.xml deployment of EAR failed.

When I search in folder Glassfish domain applications inside the deployed EAR folder I see this file structure:

```
-- .glassfishStaleFiles
-- [appName-1.0.0_war] / WEB-INF / lib / richfaces-core-impl-4.3.1.Final.jar
```

When I open .glassfishStaleFiles with a text editor I see:

```
atlanteusWeb-1.0.0_war/
atlanteusWeb-1.0.0_war/WEB-INF/
atlanteusWeb-1.0.0_war/WEB-INF/lib/
atlanteusWeb-1.0.0_war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-core-impl-4.3.1.Final.jar
```

I believe that this jar dependency file might be causing the issue, but even after updating to the latest version the error remains

to deploy the EAR again I need to shutdown Glassfish, and clean manually the applications folder, start again and deploy

Comment: Add a question and answer it yourself. Help others and earn credits. Otherwise, it seems like a question unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems an issue with existing implementation of Glassfish v.3.1.2.2 for Windows, after updating to version 4 got issue solved.